# How to write a Proof-Of-Concept(POC) for machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I've found that If any company is interested in your product, But they don't know it will fit, it will work or they don't trust you, They will ask you for a POC or Proof-Of-concept

I need to write a Proof-Of-Concept(POC) for my machine learning developed model, So how can I?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Duplicate : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545286/how-to-write-a-proof-of-conceptpoc-for-machine-learning-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof of concept for a ML model is the same as in the ML research literature:

- Design or adopt a suitable evaluation method specifically for the task. Prove that the evaluation design is appropriate, including explanation about any data collection, preprocessing, etc.
- Evaluate performance in a reliable and accurate way. Prove that the performance value that you obtain is correct with respect to the task, i.e. that the same performance will be obtained in the production environment.
- Compare the performance of your model against any relevant existing model, preferably on the same data.
- Justify any design/implementation choice